# JS autocalculate multiple fields for total

Tags: javascript

I have looked at multiple examples of js being used to auto calculate the total but haven't found any applicable for me which has fields calculating different numbers to be combined to create a total. Here is my code below so you can understand more.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Calculator</title>

<script language="javascript">
   function Calc(className){
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
      var totalCost = 0;
   
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
         totalCost += parseInt(elements[i].value);
      }
      
      document.tickets.totalCost.value = '£' + totalCost;

  }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="tickets" id="tickets">

<!--FIRST CLASS that takes the value entered and * by the ticket price for an adult. Price is £18 * Number of Tickets -->
 <label for="noAdults"> Number of Adults</label>
 <select name="noAdults" id="noAdults" class="adultTotal" onclick="Calc('adultTotal')">

  <option value="0" >0</option>
  <option value="1" >1</option>
  <option value="2" >2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
  <option value="4" >4</option>
  <option value="5" >5</option>
  <option value="6" >6</option>
  <option value="7" >7</option>
  <option value="8" >8</option>
 </select>
 <label for="pricing"> X £18</label><br><br>
 
<!--Not class as children under 2 are not charged-->

 <label for="childUnder2"> Number of Children aged 2 or less </label>
 <select name="childUnder2" id="childUnder2">

  <option value="0" >0</option>
  <option value="1" >1</option>
  <option value="2" >2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
  <option value="4" >4</option>
  <option value="5" >5</option>
  <option value="6" >6</option>
  <option value="7" >7</option>
  <option value="8" >8</option>
 </select>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=auto%20calculate%20values%20onclick#
 <label for="pricing"> X £FREE</label><br><br>
 
<!--SECOND CLASS that takes the value entered and * by the ticket price for a child ages 3-10. Price is £10 * Number of Tickets --> 
 <label for="childBox1"> Number of Children aged 3-10</label>
 <select name="childBox1" id="childBox1" class="childBox1" onclick="Calc('childBox1')">

  <option value="0" >0</option>
  <option value="1" >1</option>
  <option value="2" >2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
  <option value="4" >4</option>
  <option value="5" >5</option>
  <option value="6" >6</option>
  <option value="7" >7</option>
  <option value="8" >8</option>
 </select>
 <label for="pricing"> X £10</label><br><br>
 
<!--EDIT CLASS that takes the value entered and * by the ticket price for a child ages 11-16. Price is £13 * Number of Tickets -->
 <label for="childBox2"> Number of Children aged 11-16</label>
 <select name="childBox2" id="childBox2" class="childBox2" onclick="Calc('childBox2')">

  <option value="0" >0</option>
  <option value="1" >1</option>
  <option value="2" >2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
  <option value="4" >4</option>
  <option value="5" >5</option>
  <option value="6" >6</option>
  <option value="7" >7</option>
  <option value="8" >8</option>
 </select>
 <label for="pricing"> X £13</label><br><br>

<!--If checked, the priced is double from that of a single ticket. Total price is * 2. -->
 <input type="checkbox" name="rtnJourney" id="rtnJourney" value="2" onclick="Calc('rtnJourney')">Return Journey - If unchecked, price is halved<br>
 
Total: <input type="text" id="totalCost" name="totalCost">

</form>
</body></html>
```

Now I understand why the above JS code doesn't work and I fetched this from one of the examples online which took every value from a CLASS and combined them but since I have different multiplication values for each entry I tried to modify it which didn't workout. I am not sure how to do what I need it to do to calculate the total. Also please note that it doesn't add the values yet, for now I just want to make it calculate the total from all the fields.

p.s I am really not familiar with JS and I really appreciate any help given.

Comment: instead of onClick you might want to try onChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>

    <script language="javascript">
      var map = {
        "noAdults": {
          value: 0,
          multiplier: 18
        },
        "childUnder2": {
          value: 0,
          multiplier: 0
        },
        "childBox1": {
          value: 0,
          multiplier: 10
        },
        "childBox2": {
          value: 0,
          multiplier: 13
        }
      }
      var rtnJourney = false;

      function displayTotal() {
        var total = 0;
        for (var key in map) {
          total += map[key].value * map[key].multiplier;
        }
        total = rtnJourney ? total * 2 : total;
        document.tickets.totalCost.value = '£' + total;
      }

      function getTotal(dom) {
        map[dom.id].value = dom.value;
        displayTotal();
      }

      function getChecked(dom) {
        rtnJourney = dom.checked;
        displayTotal();

      }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <form name="tickets" id="tickets">

      <!--FIRST CLASS that takes the value entered and * by the ticket price for an adult. Price is £18 * Number of Tickets -->
      <label for="noAdults"> Number of Adults</label>
      <select name="noAdults" id="noAdults" class="adultTotal" onchange="getTotal(this)">

        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
      </select>
      <label for="pricing"> X £18</label>
      <br>
      <br>

      <!--Not class as children under 2 are not charged-->

      <label for="childUnder2"> Number of Children aged 2 or less </label>
      <select name="childUnder2" id="childUnder2" onchange="getTotal(this)">

        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
      </select>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=auto%20calculate%20values%20onclick#
      <label for="pricing"> X £FREE</label>
      <br>
      <br>

      <!--SECOND CLASS that takes the value entered and * by the ticket price for a child ages 3-10. Price is £10 * Number of Tickets -->
      <label for="childBox1"> Number of Children aged 3-10</label>
      <select name="childBox1" id="childBox1" class="childBox1" onchange="getTotal(this)">

        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
      </select>
      <label for="pricing"> X £10</label>
      <br>
      <br>

      <!--EDIT CLASS that takes the value entered and * by the ticket price for a child ages 11-16. Price is £13 * Number of Tickets -->
      <label for="childBox2"> Number of Children aged 11-16</label>
      <select name="childBox2" id="childBox2" class="childBox2" onchange="getTotal(this)">

        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
      </select>
      <label for="pricing"> X £13</label>
      <br>
      <br>

      <!--If checked, the priced is double from that of a single ticket. Total price is * 2. -->
      <input type="checkbox" name="rtnJourney" id="rtnJourney" value="2" onchange="getChecked(this)">Return Journey - If unchecked, price is halved
      <br> Total:
      <input type="text" id="totalCost" name="totalCost">

    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```